# Tab-auto slows down Wicket form

Tags: wicket

I created some phone number fields in a Wicket form. Without tab-auto, they work fine. When tab-auto is added to the HTML, it takes a few seconds for new values being entered to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get this kind of things solved is to create a "[QuickStart](http://www.jeremythomerson.com/blog/2008/11/wicket-quickstart-tutorial/)" that demonstrates your issue and post it on [Wicket's issue management system](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET).